# What is causing memory to continuously rise perl?

Tags: linux, perl, memory

#### Problem

I have created a simple perl script to read log files and process the data asynchronously.

The problem i am facing is that the script appears to continuously use more memory the longer it runs. This seems to be affected by the amount of data it processes. The problem I have is that i am unable to identify what exactly is using all this memory, and whether it is a leak or something is just holding onto it.

---

#### Question

How can i modify the below script so that it no longer continuously consumes memory ?

---

#### Code

```perl
#Multithreaded to read multiple log files at the same time.

use strict;
use warnings;

use threads;
use Thread::Queue;
use threads::shared;

my $logq = Thread::Queue->new();
my %Servers :shared;
my %servername :shared;

sub csvsplit {
        my $line = shift;
        my $sep = (shift or ',');

        return () unless $line;

        my @cells;
        my $re = qr/(?:^|$sep)(?:"([^"]*)"|([^$sep]*))/;

        while($line =~ /$re/g) {
                my $value = defined $1 ? $1 : $2;
                push @cells, (defined $value ? $value : '');
        }

        return @cells;
}


sub process_data
{
        while(sleep(1)){

                if ($logq->pending())
                {
                        my %sites;
                        my %returns;
                        while($logq->pending() > 0){
                                my $data = $logq->dequeue();
                                my @fields = csvsplit($data);
                                $returns{$fields[$#fields - 1]}++;
                                $sites{$fields[$#fields]}++;
                        }
                print "counter:$_, value=\"$sites{$_}\" />\n" for (keys%sites);
                print "counter:$_, value=\"$returns{$_}\" />\n" for (keys%returns);
                
                }
        }

}

sub read_file
{
        my $myFile=$_[0];
        open(my $logfile,'<',$myFile) || die "error";
        my $Inode=(stat($logfile))[1];
        my $fileSize=(stat($logfile))[7];
        seek $logfile, 0, 2;
        for (;;) {
                while (<$logfile>) {
                        chomp( $_ );
                        $logq->enqueue( $_ );
                }
                sleep 5;
                if($Inode != (stat($myFile))[1] || (stat($myFile))[7] < $fileSize){
                        close($logfile);
                        while (! -e $myFile){
                                sleep 2;
                        }
                        open($logfile,'<',$myFile) || die "error";
                        $Inode=(stat($logfile))[1];
                        $fileSize=(stat($logfile))[7];
                }
                seek $logfile, 0, 1;
        }

}


my $thr1 = threads->create(\&read_file,"log");
my $thr4 = threads->create(\&process_data);
$thr1->join();
$thr4->join();
```

---

#### Obeservations and relevant info

The memory only seems to increase when the program has data to process, if i just leave it, it maintains the current memory usage.

Memory only appears to increase for larger throughput and increase about half a Mb per 5 seconds for around 2000 lines in the same time.

I have not included the csv as i do not think it is relevant. If you do and want me to add it please give a valid reason.

---

#### Specs

```
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (s390x-ibm-linux-gnu)
perl, v5.10.0
```

---

I have looked through other questions but cannot find much of relevance. If this is a duplicate or the relevant info is in another question, feel free to mark as a dupe and ill check it out.

Any more info needed just ask.

Comment: Why are you recreating `qr//` on each line? It's entire point is to cache compiled regexp. Try `state $re_cache = {};
my $re = ($re_cache{$sep} //= qr/(?:^|$sep)(?:"([^"]*)"|([^$sep]*))/);`

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov Could you explain what your command does please?

Comment: [`state`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/state.html) makes a variable lexically persistent. It will always stay around for the current scope, a bit like a singleton. @Oleg's code creates a cache that stores the precompiled regex per possible separator.

Comment: It saves compiled regexp in a persistent hash with `$sep` as key, so you won't recompile regexp with any given separator more than once. `state` is perl 5.10+ feature for variables that mainain their value between leaving their scope. `//=` is "defined or" so value will be either retrieved from hash if it is already there or intialized.

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov and simbabque thanks for the explanation.

Comment: The [documentation for `threads`](https://metacpan.org/pod/threads)
 says this *"The use of interpreter-based threads in perl is officially discouraged"*. There is no explicit mention of memory leak problems, but I wouldn't rule it out. I recommend that you take a look at `fork` instead, specifically the nicely-wrapped [Parallel::ForkManager](https://metacpan.org/pod/Parallel::ForkManager) module

Comment: Your `csvsplit` should really be implemented using [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV). It's an established module that has repeatedly been shown to handle all corner cases properly

Comment: @Borodin Yeah i read that, but I though i should probably be okay. If i remember correctly, it says it's because it uses heavy threads, but as i only instantiate them once i thought it would be okay. I hadn't thought about fork though, so thanks, I'll have a look.

Comment: @Borodin I am unable to use Text::CSV as i cannot use CPAN. For most modules i just FTP up the file, but Text::CSV used compiled code and i could not find the source.

Comment: @123: Many people believe that they are unable to install modules from CPAN and I have never been able to fathom why that might be. Every module is available as a simple download, and [`Text::CSV` is here](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/MAKAMAKA/Text-CSV-1.33/) and you can download it as a tar.gz [here](http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/M/MA/MAKAMAKA/Text-CSV-1.33.tar.gz). Every CPAN module is installed in the same simple way, which is described in [perldoc perlmodinstall](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmodinstall.html). `Text::CSV` is a pure-Perl module and doesn't require a C compiler

Comment: @Borodin Thats what i normally do. The Text::CSV i found definitely had a dependency on some compiled code though. Maybe there are different versions...

Answer (score 2):

The reason is probably that the size of your `Thread::Queue` is unlimited. If the producer thread is faster than the consumer thread, your queue will continue to grow. So you should simply [limit the size of your queue](https://metacpan.org/pod/Thread::Queue#limit). For example, to set a limit of 1,000 queue items:

```
$logq->limit = 1000;
```

(The way you use the `pending` method is wrong by the way. You should only terminate if the return value is undefined.)

Comment: Please show an example of how i should use pending. Thanks for the answer. I will try it out and see if it improves the memory usage. Would the fact that i am getting output not mean that the queue was always being reduced to 0 though? Also would limiting the size of the queue mean that i would lose data ?